# ASP.NET Core not create a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I encounter this error when creating a view in the asp.net core project, what is the reason?

> there was an error running the selected code generator : 'scaffolding failed'
> could not load information for project E:\my projects\ ... \ DataLayer.csproj

and i tried different Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design versions

Comment: Could you please share your project structure and class and controller details? How did you added those file and steps need to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the *dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator* to the latest stable version may fix the issue.

```
dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```